# How to set the dsn of [inputs.sql] while using telegraf to connect MySQL?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, influxdb, telegraf

I use docker-compose.yml to deploy MySQL, InfluxDB and Telegraf. I want to write the data of a MySQL database to an InfluxDB database through Telegraf. How to set the dsn of [inputs.sql] plugin while using telegraf to connect MySQL? Here are my settings:
[image]
[image]
It is said the dsn should be set as followed:

```
username:password@protocol(address)/dbname?param=value
```

My config turn out to be wrong:

```
E! [telegraf] Error running agent: starting input inputs.sql: connecting to database failed: dial tcp 192.168.48.5:3306: connect: connection refused
```

Can you tell me how to fix it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is connection issue there. Could you first test your MySQL connection from where the Telegraf agent is deployed?

1. Open a terminal from where the Telegraf agent is deployed
2. From inside the command prompt, type the command **telnet**  3306. In your case, that would be:

> 192.168.48.5:3306

3. Hit enter to activate the command. If the MySQL service is running, you will receive a response from the server. If not, please make sure the MySQL is up and running and the firewall is clear.